# Shift or replace_z values from ALS LiDAR scans

Tags: r, lidr, lastools

I have ALS LiDAR scans that I merged into a single file and classified ground points. I'm trying to 're-scale' the Z/height values but without actually normalizing them.. What I'd like to do re-scale the non-normalized min-Z values to 0 at the ground points, and the max-Z values would be relative. The primary reason for doing this (as opposed to simply normalizing the data) is to keep the contour of the terrain for gap-fraction/light-transmittance analysis.

In LAStools, I have used the lasheight tool with the 'replace_z' option, but this appears to result in the same output as simply normalizing the scans. i.e., the min Z values are indeed 0, but the terrain is flat (when it should be moderately hilly). Any LAStools or lidR-based ideas or suggestions (I am new to LiDAR)?

The LAStools script I ran looks like:

```
-replace_z -o "merge_clip_replaceZ.laz"
```

Comment: I think that recalling is not the good word. I understant that you want to shift the Z values such as the lowest point is at Z = 0. In lidR you can do `las$Z = las$Z - min(las$Z)`

Comment: In LAStools you also have `-translate_xyz 0 0 -250` that may do the job

Comment: Thank you very much. The first option did the trick. I will check out lastools option too. If you want to add an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `lidR` you can simply substract the minimum value of `Z`

```r
las$Z = las$Z - min(las$Z)
```

In `LAStools` you have an option `-translate_xyz`. Something like that should work (not tested)

```
las2las -translate_xyz 0 0 -250 -i input.las -o output.las
```

where `250` is the Z elevation of the lowest point that must be found somehow (using `lasinfo` for example)